# How to use python to export the bake image form blender

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.76

I want to make some operationi automatic.But I met some trouble in export the image after I bake it.At first I try to use "bpy.ops.object.bake_image()" to bake the image.But the result image can not be active in uv editor.
[The bake was success,but the result image didn't appear in the uv editor.It need selected so that I could export the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSPVi.png)

So I search the document ， and found the other command "bpy.ops.object.bake()".It have a parameter "save_mode",but I still met some obstacle in using this command.It always point me out that " RuntimeError: error: No active image found in material "material" (0) for object "1.001" ".
Here is the official document about this two command:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=bake#bpy.ops.object.bake

Can anyone try to give me some solution or some advice that how can I make this thing right.

Comment: Hers is the link that I try to automatic the operation :https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/03/27/intel-realsense-3d-scanning-how-to-import-to-unity

Answer (score 2):

Many of blenders operators require a certain context to be right before they will work, for `bpy.ops.image.save()` that includes the UV/Image editor having an active image. While [there are ways](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=override%20context) to [override the current context](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) to make them work, it can often be easier to use other methods.

The Image object can [`save()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save) itself. If it is a new image you will first need to set it's `filepath`, you may also want to set it's `file_format`.

```
img = bpy.data.images['imagename']
img.filepath = '/path/to/save/imagename.png'
img.file_format = 'PNG'
img.save()
```